# InfoPath new document

Tags: infopath

I'm trying to experiment with InfoPath, but I can't even create a new document. This is what the new dialog looks like.

[image: screenshot]

Weird?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different programs: InfoPath Designer and InfoPath Filler. You appear to have opened InfoPath Filler. You will need Designer to create your own forms.